# Excel - Date and Time Autoformat

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the situation:

1. I have in a cell the following number `2012-09-13  23:38:22`
2. The cell format number is `hh:mm`
3. The number showed by the cell is `23:38`
4. The cell’s length is 43 pixels
5. When I change the cell’s number to `2012-09-13  23:38:23`
6. The cell format number change to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`
7. The cell’s length is 93 pixels
8. So what can I do to avoid the cell auto format described at step 6 and 7, and? I want to keep the cell format number to `hh:mm` and the cell’s length to 43 pixels.

Maybe I should try to start reformat macro after edition detection over a specific column?

Comment: I cannot duplicate your problem. I entered "2012-09-13 23:38:22" into a 50 pixel cell and Excel set the format as "yyyy-mm-dd  hh:mm:ss" and displayed the value as "#####". I changed the format to "h:mm" and it displayed as "23:38". I editted the value to "13/09/2012  23:38:23", I entered "13/09/2012 23:38:24" and I entered "2012-09-13 23:38:25".  In all three cases the format remained as "h:mm" and the display as "23:38".  Note in my country, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" is the default format.

Answer (score 0):

At step 6, enter the new number into a different cell, perhaps on a scratch worksheet. Then Copy - Paste Special - Values that cell to the one you were trying to change.